# Spring Junit Mockito Runner read property from test application properties file

Tags: junit, properties, mockito

My test class is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource
public class FooClassTest {

    @Value("${foo.property}")
    String property;

    ...
}
```

In my application properties, inside test/resources folder, I have the property `foo.property=some`, but when I launch FooClassTest, property is null.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the @TestPropertySource if you refer to the documenation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html) it states

> @TestPropertySource is a class-level annotation that is used to
>   configure the locations() of properties files and inlined
>   properties()....

It also states

> Test property sources have higher precedence than those loaded from
>   the operating system's environment or Java system properties as well
>   as property sources added by the application declaratively